# iOS13 can't support the background update notification?

Tags: ios13, xcode11, uibackgroundtask

iOS13 can't support the background update notification.Is this an OS-level bug?
And when app enter background,the Xcode warning shows:

> Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 1
>   (0x1), or it may have already been ended. Break in
>   UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.

Comment: Please enter your code to better explain your case and so that we can help you

Comment: Just push a silent notification to an App on ios 13 device.
like this :
{
    "aps" : {
        "content-available" : 1
    },
    "acme1" : "bar",
    "acme2" : 42
}

Comment: You can edit your own post and add your code there to make your question clearer

Comment: This is a push test , just push this type of notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the answer from the Developer Documentation：
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns

> apns-push-type
>
> (Required when delivering notifications to devices
>   running iOS 13 and later, or watchOS 6 and later. Ignored on earlier
>   system versions.) The type of the notification. The value of this
>   header is alert or background. Specify alert when the delivery of your
>   notification displays an alert, plays a sound, or badges your app's
>   icon. Specify background for silent notifications that do not interact
>   with the user.

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns) is changed. Now it says: "(Required for watchOS 6 and later; recommended for macOS, iOS, tvOS, and iPadOS) The value of this header must accurately reflect the contents of your notification’s payload. If there is a mismatch, or if the header is missing on required systems, APNs may return an error, delay the delivery of the notification, or drop it altogether.". It seems that `apns-push-type` is no longer required for `iOS`.